# How to create a link that will keep the current url path

Tags: javascript

Hello guys I need a hand with this. In the website I have to locations US  and AU.
I want for people to be able to switch between stores without loosing where they are (breadcrumb)

Let say they are here:

```
mydomain.com/us/category/item/
```

I want a link that will take you to the same path with different location across the whole website:

```
mydomain.com/au/category/item/
```

So I need some how to create AU link that will take you there

```
[mydomain.com]/[change this]/[keep same]
```

Comment: You have two answers to your question below; you should indicate whether either/neither works. (Generally, it's a good idea to stick around for a bit after you post a question, so that you can continue to give input.)

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript and Replace

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#UStoUK').click(function() {
                var url = 'mydomain.com/us/category/item/'
                url = url.replace('/us','/uk')
                window.location.href = url;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

While pshyoulost's answer works, I think you should be a little safer:

```
var formatLinkForOtherCountry = function (destination) {
    // return if you want to use this link else
    // otherwise, just do `window.location.href = window.location.href.replace...`
    return window.location.href.replace(/(.+\.com\/)(.{2})/, "$1" + destination);
}
```

Using just `url.replace('/us','/uk')` could mean that a link like `yourdomain.com/us/category/items/someWordStartingWithUs/...` would be transformed to `yourdomain.com/uk/category/items/ukmeWordStartingWithUs/...`, which wouldn't work. Instead, you can use a regular expression:

```
/                           # start regex
    (                       # open capturing group 1 ($1)
        .+\.com\/           # all characters until ".com"
    )                       # close capturing group 1
    (                       # open capturing group 2
        .{2}                # continue for two characters
    )                       # end capturing group 2
/                           # end regex
```

In the [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function, we can then replace all instances of our match (the two capturing groups) with `"$1" + destination"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` and replace:

```
function changeDir (i, s) {
    var url = location.pathname.split('/');
    url[i] = s;
    window.location.href = url.join('/');
}
```

To use this, do:

```
changeDir(URL Part, New Value);
```

An example is:

```
changeDir(1, 'uk');
```

To determine the **URL Part**. An explanation is:

```
       example.com/us/category/item

                   ⬆    ⬆      ⬆
```

```
Part:              1     2      3
```

---

Feel free to add this to the `location` object *(I have no idea if this is bad practice.)*

```
window.location.change = function (i,s) {
    var url = location.pathname.split('/');
    url[i] = s;
    window.location.href = url.join('/');
}
```